# ESRI ArcGIS : location point [using lat, long] is not rendering at correct position on arcGIS map

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I am working on a web app where I need to render the point location on a map using latitude and longitude values returned from the tracking device.

When I render lat & long positions on a map, it is some meters offset from the actual location.

## Actual location of device:

Verified from location tracker app
[image]

## Marker point when I render on ArcGIS map:

[image]

You can see it is not rendering at the correct location

For reference, I have created a pen for this issue

`codepen:  https://codepen.io/navtej887/pen/xxVXGYV`

Is this the right way to render a lat-long position on the map?

Comment: I think the coordinates are good .. I actually check it in the same page you did and it is showing me the same position in the map .. Check again and let me know .. BTW, you are doing good in your code, that is a correct way to visualize a location

Comment: it's not if you will put lat long on this web app.
long: 72.6325345 and lat:  21.1127108 
https://www.gps-coordinates.net/
you will see it is being rendered center of the intersection.

Comment: I agree it is kind of weird, but if you take a look the images are not the same. The perspective is kind of tricky. Trust in the coordinates, it is unique.